# Showing C++ pure virtual class in VS2010 watch window only shows vtable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, interface

In our software we like to use pure virtual classes for interfaces and has been working well. One small issue that has made debugging these classes rather difficult is getting the implementation values to show up in the debugger. Right now the only data I can see is the vtable of the Interface.

Is there a specific way to cast this so I can see the values of the implementation cast? or any way to view the values without always having to recompile.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pure virtual class". A class can have pure virtual member functions; that makes it an abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 will show you the derived type as the first entry in the object, named `[type]`, above the `__vfptr` field.

If you aren't seeing the derived type in the debugger, possible reasons are that your object is corrupt or optimizations are preventing the debugger from deducing the actual type of the object.

In the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfGtk.png), `b` is a `base*` initialized with `new derived(5)`.

[image: example]

```
struct base
{
    virtual bool func() = 0;
};

struct derived : public base
{
    derived(int x) { i = x; }
    virtual bool func() { return false; }
    int i;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for posting code, I was feeling a little bit lazy :( How would the use of std::shared_ptr effect this ? What I see is in the line of b I see i=??? and no [derived] for us i is not a class.  are there any particular compile flags I should look for ?

Comment: Are you compiling for release mode or debug mode? And no, `shared_ptr` has no effect. If you see i=???, it means either the compiler optimized too well for the debugger to follow or you're pointing to an invalid object.